# Jolt transform array value to object

Tags: arrays, json, jolt

I am trying to transform array value as string to my object using jolt. When I convert array value to String, I am not able to get the proper value in my object.

**Input Json :**

```
  "id": [
    "123",
    "245"
  ],
  "lastName": [
    "john",
    "Mary"
  ],
  "firstName": [
    "doe",
    "Ann"
  ],
  "subjects": [
    [
      "['Maths']",
      "['Science']",
      "['English']"
    ],
    [
      "['English']",
      "['Accounts']",
      "['Art']"
    ]
  ]
}
```

**Jolt Spec:**

```
[{
  "operation": "shift",
  "spec": {
    "*": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "$": "[&2].&3"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}]
```

**Expected output :**

```
[ {
  "id" : "123",
  "lastName" : "john",
  "firstName" : "doe",
  "subjects" : [ ["['Maths']","['Science']","['English']"] ]
}, {
  "id" : "245",
  "lastName" : "Mary",
  "firstName" : "Ann",
  "subjects" : [ ["['English']","['Accounts']","['Art']"] ]
} ]
```

**Actual Output:**

```
[ {
  "id" : "123",
  "lastName" : "john",
  "firstName" : "doe",
  "subjects" : [ "0", "1", "2" ]
}, {
  "id" : "245",
  "lastName" : "Mary",
  "firstName" : "Ann",
  "subjects" : [ "0", "1", "2" ]
} ]
```

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if this solves it. Think you were missing a level at the subjects array:

```
[{
  "operation": "shift",
  "spec": {
    "*": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "$": "[&2].&3"
        }
      }
    },
    "subjects": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "$": "[&3].&4"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}]
```

cheers